# Remap keyboard using private characters (windows 7)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard

I have created some private characters using **Windows Private Character Editor**, but I want to be able to have the keyboard type my characters based on what I want the keys to type, but every program I find, it has no Private Character functionality... What do i do?

[image: img]

Comment: oh, thanks user3128303, that might be pretty useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your ultimate goal or restrictive parameters I can only give you a couple suggestions that come to mind but which may or may not be useful to you & your situation.

1. You could create a keyboard layout with the free Microsoft tool. It is able to access & assign private use characters.  (Copy & paste the glyph from the Character Map to your custom key map.)
   [MS Keyboard Layout Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)
2. You could replace other characters/glyphs from another language which you do not use with your characters in a font making sure that the characters you replace are accessible through an already available keyboard.